# Spring Boot Auditing is Called Infinitely

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an auditor class:

```
@Component
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    private final SecurityService securityService;

    public AuditorAwareImpl(SecurityService securityService) {
        this.securityService = securityService;
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        if (securityService.getAuthenticatedUser().isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return Optional.of(securityService.getAuthenticatedUser().get().getMobilePhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

and has a security service:

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public SecurityService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Optional<User> getAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        UserDetails authUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return userRepository.findByMobilePhoneNumber(authUser.getUsername());
    }

}
```

When I try to update an entity, these two classes are called infinitely which results with a stack over flow.

I use Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.3.4.RELEASE.

How can I fix that recurrent recursion to avoid it?

Comment: I think it is a stack overflow on `components` right?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is having `@Lazy` annotation on your service at the point where it is `@Autowired` in. This is because if you don't have `@Lazy` on your component, then will be injected eagerly into the bean. So try the following and it should just work:

```
@Component
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private final SecurityService securityService;
   
    .....
}
```